# Is it possible to remove and old concrete balcony from a brick home and replace with a standard wood/composite deck?

Tags: concrete, replacement, demolition

I have a brick home built in the 1930's with a concrete slab "cantilevered" off the back of the house with 2 support columns. I am unsure if the balcony was original or added later but I do know the support columns were replaced and not in the original locations. the "newer" columns were place just to the side of the original columns and rest on the concrete patio below. I worry about its integrity, as it does not have traditional footings for the posts and its age. Is it possible to remove the balcony entirely and replace/ enlarge it with a more typical wooden balcony and deck? If DIY would be too difficult/ dangerous, what kind of contractor would I reach out too, a concrete guy?

[[image]]

[1][image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems good to me, no glaring problems/cracks.  Can have a building inspector/structural engineer check it.  It is probably built into the wall of the house itself, not just have the bricks holding it, plus being very heavy, I would want professionals to remove it, probably need a crane.

Comment: Neither cantilevered (rather, simply supported) nor in any obvious need of replacement. If you want to waste money, go ahead... Age, if anything, is in its favor (it's lasted this long, no degradation evident.)

Comment: I expect that concrete thing will outlast anything you make out of wood.

Comment: What don't you like about it?  Are you wanting to change the size or is it the look?  You could always laminate it with composite on top and composite facia on the sides.

Comment: The structure _on_ the balcony is a bit of a monstrosity, and I can see replacing that, but I'd leave the balcony itself alone.

Answer (score 4):

Of course it can be removed and replaced, but certainly safety is going to be a critical concern.  It would be very easy for the entire thing to break apart and fall down onto whatever or whoever is below.

I would definitely get someone who is well versed in concrete demolition and has references to take this down for you.  I'd be really hesitant to attempt this myself.

As far as replacing it, there are many options.

BTW - strictly speaking, this is not really "cantilevered" in its design since it's supported by those posts.  Cantilevered means supported by the structure and cantilevers but without support at the ends.